# CSS quirk with IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I'm trying to get this menu working with IE (mainly 9+ atm) and am having trouble. There seems to be some weird padding issue that I can't seem to track down. Any ideas?

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ztzn6/

IE Verion:

[image]

Chrome Version:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your second rule group (the one with `display: inline-block`). You're running into some fun rules about how line-boxes and inline elements work, IE seems to be using a different default behavior.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure out what was wrong with the padding/margin... it wasn't either of those. I'll have to store that one away and remember that quirk.